# Not able to get name property of select dropdown in Material UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, internationalization, material-ui

I am trying to implement select dropdown but while handling the onChange method, I am getting `event.target.name` as undefined.When i select the 1st option , i need to access 'English'. How do i do that.

```
const [lang, setLang] = React.useState('')

  const handleChange = event => {

    setLang(event.target.value)
  }
<Select
  id="demo-simple-select"
  value={lang}
  onChange={handleChange}
  displayEmpty
  className={classes.selectEmpty}
  renderValue={value => (
    <div>
      {fixed} <span>{value}</span>
    </div>
  )}
  MenuProps={{
    transformOrigin: {
      vertical: "top",
      horizontal: "right"
    },
    getContentAnchorEl: null
  }}
>
  <MenuItem value="" disabled>
    <LanguageIcon className={classes.content} />
    <span>
      <Trans>Languages</Trans>
    </span>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={"en"}>English</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={"ja"}>
    <span>
      <Trans>日本語 (Japanese)</Trans>
    </span>
  </MenuItem>
</Select>;
```

Comment: Could you add your code of the headler function?

Comment: @keikai I have added the code

Comment: try using `event.currentTarget.value`

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood, what is attribute name from the `event.target` object. It's the `name` of your `Select` component and not certain text for `MenuItem`.

As far as I understood what you are trying to achieve, you have to use objects for values and not a string. For example - `{ name: 'English', code: 'en' }`.

Here is [codesandbox with working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-demo-with-objects-as-values-cf1s8). Unfortunately from code, you've provided can't find out what is `{fixed}`, `<LanguageIcon>`, `<Trans>`, etc. So couldn't adapt it fully